# How to use selenium with autoit for file upload in a Headless chrome browser?

Tags: file-upload, selenium-chromedriver, teamcity, autoit, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to automate a webpage in selenium on a chrome browser  which is integrated into a TeamCity server.
The code is working perfectly in my local machine.
File upload is done with Autoit scripts but when running through TeamCity on chrome browser ,typically as a headless chrome browser ,the script fails as it fails to find the next element(The file uplod fails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible...
Headless browser cannot interact with os components(open dialog box)
You can use sendkeys to input field(browse button),which will not trigger open dialog box, since the browser is headless and you can skip using Autoit for headless browsers, which needs a Gui.